# Copying characters in a string

Tags: java, regex, replace, copy

i am trying to delete every digit from a string and then copy the letter that comes after that digit.
So for example the string   `4a2b` should output `aaaabb`.
So far my code looks like this:

```
Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String newString = s.replace(" ", "");
    newString=newString.replaceAll("\\W+", "");
    newString=newString.replaceAll("\\d+", "");
    System.out.println(newString);
```

Is it possible to use regex and replaceAll to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
   String newString = "4a2b";
    String num = "";
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < newString.length(); i++) {
        char ch = newString.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            num += ch;

        } else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (num.length() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt(num); j++) {
                    res.append(ch);
                }
            }
            num="";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: This will result in "4a2b" becoming "aaab" which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Still won't work. The OP wants the "4a" to become "aaaa" and "2b" to become "bb".

Comment: Should probably add that it should work for every letter, not just a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "ae4a2bca";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(.)").matcher(str);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
    {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, times("$2", Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

private static String times(String string, int t)
{
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) str += string;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: It's also the one that uses regex as the OP requested.